# Android - Use of Library: Local Jar versus online link

Tags: android, jar, shared-libraries, jcenter

Some of my apps use publicly available libraries. I feel comfortable downloading such libraries as jar files, given that the code of a jar stored locally is "safe" with me.

Sometimes, however, the library is only available to be added as a dependency in the module's build.gradle, as below:

```
implementation 'com.darth.vader.lib.filechooser:filechooser:1.1.0'
```

This worries me because I have zero control over that code, and no clue if/when it changes.

Can somebody enlighten me on the pros & cons of the 2 approaches? And, on how I can "save" such "dependency" code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where the `filechooser:1.1.0` comes from, you do know when it changes (never).

Once the version is published in an immutable repository like [maven-central](/questions/tagged/maven-central) or [jcenter](/questions/tagged/jcenter) you can expect the version to remain immutable.